# SubClass extends LinkedList<SuperClass> Properties

Tags: java, object, inheritance, linked-list, subclass

I'm working with superclass and subclass. My subclass extends the SuperClass this way:

`public class SubClass extends LinkedList<SuperClass>`

Does this mean that my subclass hold LinkedList properties. For example, if I'm creating objects of my subclass from other classes, am I able to do something like:

```
public class another {
    private SubClass object;
    public another(ArrayList<String> list) {
         object = new SubClass();
         SubClass localObject = object;
         for (String elements : list) {
             localObject.addAll(elements); 
         }
    }
}
```

I want to add elements to end of the linked list.

Would this work? Or would I have to create add(), addAll() etc methods in the subclass in order for it to work?

Comment: Why don't you try it?

Comment: @shmosel I did! However, the compiler shows an error that says "no suitable method found for add(element)" and proposes that I make one in the SubClass

Comment: Because `element` is a `String`, which you can't add to a `List<SuperClass>`.

Comment: @shmosel Yes, it is. I just want to know because the SubClass extends LinkedList, does it already have add() and the like built in. Otherwise, I would just write them in the SubClass.

Comment: You can only add generic type <SuperClass> in the above code.

Comment: Hello @ZinMinn ! I don't understand, could you elaborate?

Comment: @Ani, yes, a subclass will inherit its superclass's methods.

Comment: @shmosel Alright, so you suggest I manual write the add() methods in the SuperClass?

Comment: @Ani, at least one of us is very confused.

Comment: @Ani ...Generics let you enforce compile-time type safety on Collections. LinkedList<SuperClass> can accept references of type SuperClass and any other subtype of SuperClass. **String** is not a subtype of your **SuperClass**. So you can't do .

Comment: can you post the code snippet of what you have tried.. And yes, all the public methods of superclass will be visible in the subclass inheriting it.

Comment: @ZinMinn LinkedList<? extends SuperClass> can accept references of type SuperClass and any other subtype of SuperClass.... not LinkedList<SuperClass>

Comment: @AkashLodha ... No, **LinkedList<Animal>** can add like this. LinkedList<Animal> ani_list = new LinkedList<>();
  ani_list.add(new Dog());

Comment: Hi @AkashLodha I just updated the example similar to something I'm working on! What do you think?

Comment: @AkashLodha, unless by *references of type SuperClass* you mean *a list parameterized with type SuperClass*, your statement is completely incorrect.

Comment: Stop changing your code (with complete nonsense - the last update was trying to add `int` elements to the list) while people are already answering your question. If you want to provide further details, add them to the bottom of your post but don't change the code that you have already posted significantly.

Comment: @ErwinBolwidt Sorry about that - I'm new to the site so I'm still getting used to how things work around here. In addition, I think it's completely uncalled for on your behalf to say something that condescending - referring to my work as "complete nonesense". As you can tell, I'm a beginning programmer. I think you might recall of a time where you were also beginning to program. I don't think you'd like it if you're reaching for help and someone calls it "complete nonesense".

Answer (score 1):

`SubClass` inherits all the methods of `LinkedList`, but since it `extends LinkedList<SuperClass>` it can contain only objects of type `SuperClass`.

Your code at

```
for (String elements : list) {
         localObject.addAll(elements);
```

has two problems.

1. The method `addAll` takes a `Collection<? extends T>`, which in your case is `Collection<SuperClass>` but you are passing in a single `String`.
2. Even if you modified it to pass in a collection of `String` it would still fail to compile.  Only a `Collection<SuperClass>` is acceptable here.

If you changed it to

```
for (String element : list) {
         localObject.add(element);
```

i.e. change to the `add` method instead of `addAll`, this is still wrong because the `add()` method in `SubClass` only takes objects of type `SuperClass`.

Comment: Would it work better if I changed it to a regular for-loop? I just made the change.

Comment: That has nothing to do with the problem.  Go back and re-read my answer carefully.

Comment: Yeah - I thought so. What would be the correct way for add elements to end of the SubClass linkedlist then? Manual write in addAll() methods into the SuperClass?

Comment: You can add elements with `add()`, but those elements have to be `SuperClass` instances, not `String`s.

Comment: Alright, I'll try something. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 1):

Jim Garrison is correct.  But let me make it concrete.

The class called Float extends the class called Number
Integer is another class that also extends Number.

If you create a list of numbers (aka `List<Number>`) then you can put floating point numbers in that list, and you can put integers in that list.
The following code will compile cleanly.

```
List<Number> numberList = new LinkedList<Number>();
numberList.add(new Float(1.5));
numberList.add(new Integer(1));
```

You can not, however, add a potato to a list of numbers.  Nor can you add a String, or any other type of object which is not a Number (or subclass of Number).  The following code will generate the compile time error you cited.

```
list.add("this is a String.");
```

Getting back to your code now.

First let me say that when you extend `List<SuperClass>`, this gets you another `List<SuperClass>` with a different name, Subclass in this case.  Which is to say SubClass is a list containing SuperClass objects.  You could add some additional methods to your newly named class to differentiated it from `List<SuperClass>` but first and foremost it is just a list containing instances of SuperClass.    I think you knew that already but I want to be clear.

Your method called `another` accepts an argument that is a list of strings (`List<String>`).  So that means that every member of that list, is a String.  But you are trying to pulls stuff out of that list (of strings) and then add it to a list of SuperClass.     But the list of SuperClass can ONLY accept instances of SuperClass (whatever that is).   So unless SuperClass happens to be a super class of String (and String only extends Object), then you will get an error.

Comment: Hi @Teto The instances in the SuperClass are all of String type.

Comment: You seem to be saying that SuperClass is String or a subclass of string.  Remember, to put a String into a List of SuperClass, then SuperClass must be either exactly String or exactly Object.    If SuperClass is a subclass of String, you can not put a String in a list of SuperClass.

Comment: By the way ...String can't have subclass..it is final class :-)